# how to use MySQL key_len in explain statement to defined whether a sql is fast or not?

Tags: mysql

> The key_len column indicates the length of the key that MySQL decided to use.

MySQL's docs mantion this. but i don't figure out how to use this statement to defined a sql is fast or not. the smaller key_len, the faster sql it is(please forgive my english grammarT_T)? and how it works?

expect for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This parameter makes sense for composite keys only. The server may use either the whole index completely or some prefix of it only. And key_len allows to define what prefix part of composite index is used.

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5046d5445aec9caec1f3e628a945a739)

Comment: thanks for your answer, the demo makes it very easy to understand. additionally, my understanding below would be corrected or not: the bigger key_len, the faster we can find the target data.

Comment: @zihaoQ *the bigger key_len, the faster we can find the target data.* No. Bigger length needs more disk readings, more memory for storing, more time for comparing. Main factor which affects is index cardinality and condition selectivity.

Comment: i thought that the bigger key_len makes rows statement smaller, it might be faster. thanks for bringing disk readings/storing/comparing up, it helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

(In addition to what Akina says...)

`key_len` is a bit confusing.

- It includes the length(s) of the column(s) that are used in the `WHERE`
- It does not include column(s) that it uses for "covering" or `GROUP BY` or `ORDER BY`.
- The lengths have 1 added for `NULLable`, 1 or 2 for 'VARCHAR', 4x for utf8mb4 collation, etc.
- Even though `VARCHAR(100)` will show a key_len of 402, the actual space used in the index will depend on the actual text.  A row with "Hello" will take 5+2 bytes.
- The size of key_len has very little correlation to performance.  It *does* correlate to the sizes of the column(s) involved.  The most important factor in performance is the number of rows that are touched -- either in the index or in the data.  (Those are two separate BTrees -- in the case of a "secondary key".)
- key_len has no impact on the *data*, only on the *index's BTree*.
- InnoDB fetches BTree blocks in units of 16KB.
- A bigger key (usually) means few entries per block.  This can slow down the query.
- On the other hand, the blocks you need are likely to be cached in the buffer_pool due to recently executed queries.